# A single wordpress page is not showing updates

Tags: php, html, wordpress, caching, cpanel

When i update a page on my site it shows the updated content only to me "admin" but users still see the old content. It's the only page that has this issue on my site. Any tips about the possible reasons for this and ways to fix?

My site is wordpress.

Comment: the page may be private - have you checked that in the page document settings?

Comment: Yes, its public @anmari

Comment: Hi Amr1, it's a good on stack to describe what research you have done, what you have tried etc. http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/post.php?post=151 , not to have people drag out of you what the situation is. For example presumably you have already considered cache issues, but you haven't stated that. Suggest research a bit, then update your question.  Describe also what other plugins etc you have that might have impact. Did you get users to clear their browser cache etc etc   https://mhthemes.com/support/knb/solving-common-cache-issues-on-wordpress-websites/